# Delete particular variable in character vector

Tags: r

Sorry for the dummy question. 
I have character vector

```
A
" " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " "*" " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " "." " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " "*" "*" " " " " " " " " " "" " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " "
```

Row 31 has `"."`, how can i delete it, so that it would be `""`?
I tried `gsub`, but it didn't work 
Thank you for any tips

Comment: Use `sub(".", "", v1, fixed=TRUE)` or escape it `sub("\\.", "", v1)`

Comment: im afraid the dot is still there

Comment: Then, it must not be a dot.  For example `v1 <- c(".", "tse");v1 <- sub(".", "", v1, fixed=TRUE); v1#
[1] ""    "tse"`

Comment: did you use `fixed = TRUE` ?

Comment: Oh yes! it worked, my fault. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can either use `fixed=TRUE` in `sub` or escape (`\\`) the `.` as it is a metacharacter which if left itself means any character in the string.

```
sub(".", "", v1, fixed=TRUE)
```

Or

```
sub("\\.", "", v1)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(".", "tse")
```